# How to rewrite query string to hash in the URL?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am looking to rewrite:

```
www.mysite.com/services/category1/?content=service1
```

to

```
www.mysite.com/services/category1/#tab-service1
```

I have this specific rewrite that I want to generalize for all the possible URLs on the site:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} content=service1
RewriteRule ^services/category1  services/category1/#tab-service1? [NE,R,L]
```

I tried the following but it didn't work :( -

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} content=([a-zA-Z]+)
RewriteRule ^services/category1/?content=(.*)$  services/category1/#tab-$1 [NE,R,L]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You rule looks fine except for 1 thing

QUERYSTRING `content=service1`

isn't part of match in RewriteRule's pattern so you can't test query string (Url part after the ?) in pattern of a RewriteRule. To test url query string we use  `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable like the one you are already using.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} content=([a-zA-Z]+)
RewriteRule ^services/category1/?$  services/category1/#tab-%1 [NE,R,L]
```

Comment: This is not working. It doesn't rewrite the URL at all. I tried going to www.mysite.com/services/category/?content=service_one and it just stays there.

Comment: leading slash was missing.  I added that to the pattern.  Try my edited code

Comment: Ok. I did that and now it is going to www.mysite.com/services/category/?content=service_one#tab-service_one. It is not removing ?content=service_one

Comment: @Blueboye To remove the old query string from the destination path ,put a `?` at the end of the target path like `services/category1/#tab-%1?` .

Comment: Amazing. It worked :D. I just have one more question: How can I generalize it further so that I don't have to write a rule for every category (I have multiple categories)? So it becomes something like RewriteRule ^whateverishere/?$ whateverishere/#tab-%1

Comment: @Blueboye If you have multiple urls of this format `www.mysite.com/services/anycat/?content=foobar`

You can use :


`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} content=([a-zA-Z]+)
RewriteRule ^services/(.+)/?$ services/$1/#tab-%1? [NE,R,L]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165337/discussion-between-blueboye-and-starkeen).